# how to get actual time and date in swift3

Tags: ios, image, swift3

**I am trying to upload a image to server**

My url is - https://www.zdoof.com/api/zTimeline/insert_post

My Parameters are  -

```
       "Is_checkin" : "0",
        "Description" : self.cookingText.text!,
        "Videolink" : "",
        "Post_image" : imageStr,
        "Created_by" : "4490",
        "Created_on" : "10/Oct/2017"

  The parameter(Created_on) taking the date & time  format like (dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss).
```

when i am giving only the date format like(10/Oct/2017) , the upload is success . But by default is taking time like 12:00:00 .

But i want to give the actual time as parameter .so how to encode the date and time format ,so that it will give the actual time.

for date and time my code is -

```
 let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy"

    let date = Date()
    let myString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    let data = myString.data(using: .utf8)



    self.dateString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!

  )


    let timeFormatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour,from: NSDate() as Date)
    let minute = calendar.component(.minute,from: NSDate() as Date)
    let second = calendar.component(.second,from: NSDate() as Date)

    let hourString = String.init(describing: hour)
    let minuteString = String.init(describing: minute)
    let secondString = String.init(describing: second)
    self.timeString = hourString + ":" + minuteString + ":" + secondString
```

Please help me to convert date and time to actual date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Please keep in mind that dateFormatter is 'expensive" so it will be nice to have some helper class with static or singleton dateFormatter object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with it:

```
 let formatter = DateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
 let fullDateString = formatter.string(from: Date())

 formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
 let timeString = formatter.string(from: Date())
```